# Live HTML Search Bar

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am working on a self project at the moment and am trying to implement a live search bar that filters divs using jQuery. expect I have dives within divs and when it filters based off the search bar it removes all the other divs that are connected to it and only shows the name. I have pastes the code below of my jQuery (sourced from internet), and my HTML file. I feel like its an easy fix but im not sure.

jQuery:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
         var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
         $("#contentsBox *").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
         });
      });
   });
</script>
```

Html:

```
#Search Bar
<div class="search-bar">
   <form action="#">
      <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
   </form>
</div>

#Genrated Boxs
{% for truck in trucks %}
   <div class="truckContent">
      <a href="/foodtrucks/{{truck[1]}}">
         <div class="truck-coverImg">
            <img src={{truck[11]}} alt={{truck[12]}}>
         </div>
         <div class="truck-logo">
            <img src={{truck[6]}} alt={{truck[7]}}>
         </div>
         <div class="truck-name" id="truck-name">
            <h4>{{truck[1]}}</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="truck-category">
            <h4>{{truck[2]}}</h4>
         </div>
      </a>
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The truck[x] info has been sent trough via python and is connected to a database which is created using the the data via the link: https://www.bnefoodtrucks.com.au/api/1/trucks

The generated boxes look like so:

[image: generated boxes]

And currently when i filter it dose this:

[image: filtered boxes image]

So i want it to keep all of the contents inside it like seen in the first image when searched for

Comment: Please do not throw around wrong names. You repeatly throw around `Java`. `Java` is a server-sided language and not the same as `JavaScript` (client sided language run from the browser). Your code snippet however indicates `jQuery` which is different to Java and JS.

Comment: `$("#contentsBox *")` looks at every single element in the contentsBox (including the `<a>`, `<h4>`, `<img>` etc)`. You want a far more specific selector than that and only toggle each product's container

Comment: @tacoshy sorry about that, I am still new to all the names and types of code. My bad.

Comment: @charlietfl how do i go about making it more specific can i go ``` $("#contentsBox .id") ``` of what do you suggest?

Comment: More like `$("#contentsBox .truckContent").filter... `

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, that's exactly what it was I tried something like that before but id didn't have the right formatting and so fourth. thankyou